# jQuery EasyUI datagrid: Sort on static data not working

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I have a very simple table using the most very basic features of jQuery EasyUI and it just won't sort for me.  Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyMQr/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo.css">

    <script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="easyui-datagrid" title="Unallocated Subnets" data-options="singleSelect:true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-options="field:'a',width:80,sortable:true">A</th>
                <th data-options="field:'b',width:80,sortable:true">B</th>
                <th data-options="field:'c',width:80,sortable:true">C</th>
                <th data-options="field:'d',width:80,sortable:true">D</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>b</td><td>b</td><td>b</td><td>b</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

All that is needed for client side sorting is setting:

```
remoteSort:false
```

Comment: What a geilivable answer!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the Sorting example on the jquery-easyui and it looks like it was designed to work with server side `(php)` data.  Or data loaded into the grid from a database.  And not on hard coded data like in your example.

Take a look at this example.. And notice the php code included with it.  And the example you can download at the bottom.

```
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid8.php
```

Comment: sorry i edited wrong post I added those properties, I did not imagine I can edit somebody's else post...

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for same functionality.
It seems that you need to define your own sorter per this post
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid14.php

There is also properties:

- sortName
- sortOrder
  give it a try....

Answer (score 0):

you can try the code like this, it's work

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid" title="somedata" sortName="a" sortOrder="desc" remoteSort="false">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th field="a" width="80" sortable="true">A</th>
        <th field="b" width="80">B</th>
        <th field="c" width="80">C</th>
        <th field="d" width="80">D</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

try it here http://jsfiddle.net/kapasaja/gyMQr/6/